# How to use tomcat or jenkins using docker containers

Tags: docker

I installed and started tomcat in a centos docker container. But I am unable to open tomcat in browser using `HOST-IP:8080`. It is showing error that `this site can't be reached.`

Comment: Put you `Dockerfile` please

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow please mention the link of container you have used and the command or docker file you have used to launch your docker container

Comment: First I pulled the latest Centos image and started the new container. Inside that container, I downloaded tomcat9 package (link: http://mirrors.wuchna.com/apachemirror/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.14/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.14.tar.gz) and extracted the package and started the tomcat server using startup.sh file. 
After that, I tried to open tomcat in the browser using container-IP:8080 and also tried using host-IP:8080. But both didn't work for me.

Comment: I am running docker using "docker toolbox" on a windows machine